# isotope sort by date

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to get isotope V2.2.2) to sort by date on this page: http://www.vanadiumcorp.com/blog-test, but the articles are not being sorted by date. Seem to be coming randomly.

Here is the code I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
                $('#itemListPrimary').isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.itemContainer',
                    /*percentPosition: true,*/
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
                    },
                    getSortData: {
                    byDate: function ($elem) {
            return Date.parse($elem.find(time).attr('datatime'));
                }
                    },
                    sortBy: 'byDate',
                    sortAscending: false
                });
            });
        });
```

I also tried just having:

```
return $elem.find(time).attr('datatime');
```

but that didn't work either.

I am not getting any JS errors.

The HTML code block looks like this:

```
<div class="masonary-content-wrapper">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h2 itemprop="name">
  </div>
  <dl class="article-info muted">
    <dt class="article-info-term"> Details </dt>
    <dd class="published">
      <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
      <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-08-11T09:43:32-07:00"> August 11, 2014 </time>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Appreciate any help figuring out how to get the articles to sort properly by the date in the time tag's datetime field.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `$elem.find(time).attr('datatime')` returns what you need and not just `null`?

Comment: Hi, no, I am not sure. I don't know how to find out what it is returning.

Comment: Hi, I setup a jFiddle here: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/ljk999/kumqua9x/28/. There isn't a JS error, but it isn't displaying the data in date order. How do I find out what is being returned in by: Date.parse($($elem).find('.l49-publish-date').attr('datatime'));

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
byDate: function ($elem) {
    return Date.parse($($elem).find(time).attr('datetime'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, no that doesn't work either. Says it returns NaN. 
`$($elem).find('.l49-publish-date').attr('datatime')` is undefined same with

Comment: @LJK it should be `datetime`, sorry for typo

Comment: Hi, thank you so much it is working great now. I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: @LJK You are welcome. For the future: you should avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks" - they do not contain any useful information. Use upvotes/downvotes and mark answers as right instead